# Continuous second derivative over the support of a Daubechies4 wavelet

Tags: derivatives, continuity, signal-processing, wavelets

I can not entirely follow the proof from section 3.1.1 from the book ["A primer on Wavelets"](http://people.uwec.edu/walkerjs/Primer/) by Walker. After the first part (listed below), I can grasp the rest so if you could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Given a level 1 Daub4 Wavelet:
\begin{equation}W_m^1 = (0, 0, \dots, 0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, \beta_4, 0, \dots, 0)\end{equation}
with the non-zero entries starting at position $2(m-1)$, we have the following properties:
\begin{equation}\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 + \beta_4 = 0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}0\beta_1 + 1\beta_2 + 2\beta_3 + 3\beta_4 = 0\end{equation}
and given a signal $f$ sampled at a constant step-size 
\begin{equation}h = t_{n+1} - t_n, \forall n\end{equation}
from an analog signal $g$ that is known to have a continuous second derivative over the support of $W_m^1$ such that
\begin{equation}f_n=g(t_n)\end{equation}
the author says we can write:
\begin{equation}g(t_{2m-1+k}) = g(t_{2m-1}) + g(t_{2m-1})'(kh) + {\cal O}(h^2)\end{equation}
where ${\cal O}(h^2)$ is a quantity that is a bounded multiple of $h^2$.

Why? How does $g(t_{2m-1+k})$ link that way to $g(t_{2m-1})$? Is there a property of
$g(t_{2m-1} + t_k)$ that I'm missing and that leads to the above expansion?

Comment: I think the $\mathcal O(h^2)$ is just the remainder term in [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable). Also, I would think that in the context of your question, the $k$ in $t_{2m-1+k}$ is bounded (something like $k\leq 4),$ and doesn't grow arbitrarily large. Is that so?

Comment: $k$ is probably bounded (the book doesn't state that about it) because the support of $f$ is finite. It's clear to me now, thanks to your comment, that if we take $a=2m-1$ in the Taylor series then the expression is indeed a first order Taylor expansion with $(kh)$ resulting from $t_{2m-1+k} - t_{2m-1}$. Cheers! (P.S. you should turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it)